# Cell phone battery with solar shield, arduino

Tags: arduino, batteries, solar-cell

I was looking for your opinion on this product: http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Solar_Charger_Shield_v2.0b

Do you think I could use a cell phone battery (3.7v 1000mA) with this? I have a standard Li-Ion battery with these specs that seems to work fine with this product, but I'm not sure if there is anything special about a cell phone battery that would cause it to explode or act differently if hooked up to this solar shield.

I was looking at a cell phone battery like this one: [http://www.amazon.com/LG-1100mAh-Standard-Battery-manufactured/dp/B000IBRSIS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000IBRSIS)

I was thinking I would just epoxy (not solder) on some leads to a JST connector.

Can I just leave the third terminal empty? I think it is usually to sense heat or charge or something, right?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want other good answers you should rephrase the question as I want to do xxx, how can I achieve it. One potential commercial solution I am aware of is xxx. Is there a better way that I can do this myself?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That circuit uses the [CN3083 LiIon charger IC](http://seeedstudio.com/wiki/images/4/41/CN3083.pdf) <- datasheet.

It can work with batteries with or without temperature sensors.
 If the IC specs suit your need the circuit will work as well as the CN3083 does.

Horrendously drawn [Charger shield cct diagram here](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/images/1/1f/Solar_Charger_Shield_.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

**Legal Disclaimer: Li-ion batteries can catch fire if overcharged, or improperly charged, or exposed to heat so be very very careful. I don't guarantee this advice won't cause damage or loss, or hurt you or anyone else.**

Yes, it looks like you should be able to. As long as your circuit doesn't overcharge your battery or exceed it's charging rate you should be fine.